# Ionic Facebook Api invalid key hash

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework, facebook-authentication

I can't get my app to allow Facebook login. Everytime the users tries to login to Facebook and authenticate my app with their FB, it gives me this error:

> Invalid key hash. They key hash xxxxxxxxxx= does not match any stored key hashes. configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxxxxx

I've already tried creating a new key hash through the OpenSSL tool like so:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Doing this gives me a key hash, which I then add into the 'Key Hashes' list on the developer page for the app. I then use ionic to rebuild the app, and when I run it on my android phone it gives the same error. There is another version of the app that was built on another computer, and a different hash key was used, and that worked perfectly, but the hash key from this computer doesn't seem to want to work. Any help would be great

Answer (score 9):

- On **Windows**:
  `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`
- On **Mac**:
  `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

The **password** is android.

Also see the [Ionic docs](https://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/facebook-native.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Following steps solved my problem

1. Go to facebook account inside settings > Apps and Websites > Logged in with Facebook > Active > click on ur app > And Remove App
2. After doing that try to login now and this time you will get facebook error code 1349195 : something like go to facebook docs/android page and do the setting
3. Now run the command from yours teminal

`keytool -list -printcert -jarfile yourapkname.apk`

Copy the SHA1 value and convert that into base64 and paste that base64 value into you facebook account and then try login.

To convert sha1 to base64, you can use http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php

Comment: I can't tell you how long I've been dealing with this issue.  I wonder the same thing as you...how can I verify the hashkey packaged in the app with what I'm storing in firebase.  I ran your command and it showed that the hash key packaged with the APK was different from the one I was generating locally.  I bet it's because it's using the hashkey in home ./android and not the one in my user/.android but I don't know why.  And while I can just manually copy that hash key to firebase I don't know how to format it for facebook.  anyway this was a huge hurdle...i really appreciate your post.

Answer (score 2):

He had the same problem. My solution:

On ubuntu:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /home/"username"/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

(replaces your "username")

Now you need to enter password, Password = android

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First check that the length is good for the key hash.
Second check that you don't have letters like O and 0, l and I, they look the same (one is thicker than the other).