# Facebook login ionic 4 Capacitor

Tags: android, ionic4, capacitor

I am working on Facebook login in ionic 4 capacitor. Facebook login is working fine when the device does not have any Facebook app. But it does not work when the device has Facebook App. It's showing me this error: [image: Error displaying]

I have tried many ways but couldn't find any solution. My keh hash is perfect.

Comment: Hey, can you please post code or referred link. I am also facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your facebook setting like this :

[image]

[image]

I added this answer because i can't add comment with photo .

Comment: What about key hash field??

Comment: What about the class name field??

Comment: you can read more about hash field  from this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905610/ionic-facebook-api-invalid-key-hash

Class name this mean when user complete login successfully return user to this class . 

and also you can read this about class name  : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/what-is-the-default-activity-class-name-from-androidmanifest-xml/17785/5

Comment: Thank you for the response, should I need to sign the apk file??

Comment: Thank you too , 
I think no ,  you don't need to sign it

Comment: I have generated hash key but it does not work. It works when Facebook app is not installed in my mobile. But doesn't work when I have Facebook app in my mobile. What does it mean?? Can you please figure out this situation?

Comment: I don't know what the problem exactly, but you can debug it from google chrome inspect devtools, please take a screenshot.